# How to make a loop on code in pynput without using ram and that is infinite

Tags: python, pynput

Im having a bit of trouble looping this code im new to python and coding and trying to make this an afk machine for a game i play

This is code that im trying to make that types something over and over infinitely, please help im trying to make an afk machine since my program i use ran out of trail days so im trying to make this im new to this so sorry for the stupid question but ive tried For loops and while loops and i cant get them to work

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time


keyboard = Controller ()

time.sleep(0.1)
for char in "vcmine start":
    keyboard.press(char)
    keyboard.release(char)
    time.sleep(0.03)

keyboard = Controller()

keyboard.press(Key.enter)
keyboard.release(Key.enter)
```

Comment: What does it do?

Comment: its meant to say the same word over and over forever as an afk machine

Comment: I guess I meant what happens when you run it now? I’d start by adding print statements in the loop so you can see the output on the terminal to make sure that is working. Also open a notepad document and place the cursor in it to see if anything is being typed. I’m away from my computer but I’ll try to debug in a minute.

Comment: It seems to work fine when I run it as is. In fact after having used the editor to paste the code I actually see it type into the editor. Seems to work fine. Note: where the code actually prints depends on where the cursor is located, so if you want it to print to a selected location you might want to add a wait loop that listens for a non ascci key (maybe f2) to be pressed before typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could literally just do something like this.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller, Listener
import time

def on_press(key):
    print('{0} pressed'.format(
        key))

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} release'.format(
        key))
    if key == Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

# Collect events until released
with Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()

keyboard = Controller ()# You should only need to define this once
while(True):# This will repeat the indented code below forever   
    time.sleep(0.1)
    for char in "vcmine start":
        keyboard.press(char)
        keyboard.release(char)
        time.sleep(0.03)

    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
# However the only way you can stop it is by closing the program
```

This is pretty much just copied and pasted from https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/keyboard.html
under the section Monitoring the Keyboard.
First run the code, then place the cursor where you want the text to be typed, then by hitting the esc key on the keyboard the rest of the code will now run and will type what you want where you want it.

Also note that if you run the code and then put the cursor in another text field while this is running it will start to type there instead.

for and while loops can be confusing at first but definitely read up on them because they are used a lot in coding and are very useful. While Python is my favorite language it has a bit more variety with respect to how loops can be defined which might be kind of confusing at first.

Use google ALOT to find tutorials and YouTube videos on the subject (there's tons of great info out there).

Comment: ive just tested it does not loop the activate thing is cool but im afraid that holding it in to type is not my thing i just wanna run it then it types and for it to type "vcmine start" repeatedly since i dont know how to loop

Comment: Just put while(True): and then everything you want to repay inside it.

Comment: Idk how though I’m new to this

Comment: You'll definitely want to check out some tutorials (https://www.learnpython.org/en/Loops) on basic loops. When I first started coding a few years ago they were very confusing, but after a while (no pun intended) it becomes as natural as reading. The main difference is that a "while" loop continues to run a given condition is no longer met. A "for" loop will run in a loop a specific number of times. In your case the for loop loops over each characters (letters) in the string (whats in quotes) it reaches the end of the string.

Comment: I have checked them out it’s just confusing because the tutorials show a short piece of code like just print a word but I want to make a whole code paragraph repeat

Comment: from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time

keyboard = Controller ()

while True:
for char in "vcmine start":
    keyboard.press(char)
    keyboard.release(char)
    time.sleep(0.03)
    break
while True:
    keyboard.press(key.enter)
    keyboard.press(key.enter)
    break

Comment: The second while loop will never start because the first one is set to run forever. Put everything you want to repeat in the first while(True) loop. I updated the original Answer to show this, so just copy and paste that solution, it ran for me fine. Just remember if you click out of the target text field it will stop typing in at the target instead target whatever you click just like if it was a regular keyboard.